# I need to get total HTTP requests per endpoint within a time range

Tags: .net, prometheus, grafana

I am currently using the ["official" dotnet dashboards for Grafana](https://github.com/dotnet/aspire/tree/main/src/Grafana). Overall they work great, *however*, the panel for "Top 10 Requested Endpoints" doesn't seem correct. The values seem abnormally high, and they also don't change as I would expect when setting a new time range.

The query is as follows

```
topk(10,
  sum by (http_route, http_request_method, method_route) (
    label_join(max_over_time(http_server_request_duration_seconds_count{job="$job", app_name="$appname"}[$__rate_interval]), "method_route", " ", "http_request_method", "http_route")
))
```

which produces results [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZHkH.png).

What I'd like this to do is show me the top 10 endpoints where the count is the total number of requests during the selected time range.

I'm new to Prometheus and OpenTelemetry in general, so I'm not sure what I'm missing to accomplish what I want.

I've tried a bunch of different combinations of `sum`, `count`, `sum_over_time`, `count_over_time`, `$__interval`, `$__range`, `$__rate_interval`, `increase`, etc. to no avail. Maybe I'm just dumb but I feel like this should be simple.

Comment: Hm, `max_over_time` for metric that is essentially counter seems out of place.

Comment: @markalex I agree. I've tried `sum_over_time` and `count_over_time` as well but that doesn't help.
I'm currently messing with a query like `topk(10, sum by (http_route, http_request_method, method_route) (increase(http_server_request_duration_seconds_count{job="$job", app_name="$appname"}[$__range])))` and it seems *closer* but not quite there. I would expect the resulting graph to be constantly increasing, but there are ups and downs in it.

Comment: For what you described, I'd start with query like `topk(10, sum by (http_route, http_request_method) ( increase(http_server_request_duration_seconds_count{job="$job", app_name="$appname"}[$__range]) ))`

Comment: @markalex Ha, I literally just replied with a query nearly identical to that.

Comment: Indeed. But if you want to preserve `method_route` (so that column Endpoint stays the same as in the screenshot), you also need to use `label_join`.

Comment: @markalex, I've got that, but I would still expect the graph to exclusively trend upwards, starting from 0. Furthermore, if I run the same query against another app, the results seem wildly high, most are 20k+ for the past hour.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to investigate your data then. Query simply `http_server_request_duration_seconds_count{job="$job", app_name="$appname"}` and analyze if it has values you'd expect or not.

Comment: @markalex I think I might want `delta`. From the docs it looks like it's the difference between the first and last values in a series. Does that sound correct?

Comment: You have a counter (it is in fact part of histogram, but `..._count` behaves as counter. Thus you need `increase`, not `delta`. Latter is for gauges. Difference is behaviour near resets (exporter restarts): delta will produce negative values.

Comment: @markalex This illustrates my problems perfectly, I think. The increase doesn't match up with the raw counter. This is for the past 5 minutes, the count doesn't change in that time, and I would expect the `increase` to return 0. The top line is the `increase` and the bottom is raw count
https://i.imgur.com/8tAy48e.png

Comment: I don't know what to say. It doesn't look right. Increase with data shown should be 0. Can you reproduce the same on Prometheus itself (replacing `$__range` with actual range of the graph)?